# Why are the additional crossjoins generated in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql

*Hibernate Query*

```
hql.append("FROM TBucket t1 JOIN FETCH t1.prd JOIN FETCH t1.psAct ");
```

*Configuration*

```
TBucket
@Table (name = "vw_f_t_bucket")

      @ManyToOne (cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Posprd.class)
      @JoinColumns({
          @JoinColumn(name = "prod_key", referencedColumnName="prod_key"),
          @JoinColumn(name = "prod_cycle_key", referencedColumnName="cycle_key"),
      })

      public IPosprd getprd() {
        return prd;
      }

prd ( 

@Table (name = "snp_prd")
public class Posprd implements IPosprd {

)


      @ManyToOne (cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Pospsact.class)
      @JoinColumn (name = "ps_act_key", nullable = false)
      public IPospsact getpsact() {
            return psAct;
      }      

psAct (
    @Table (name = "vw_ps_act_firm")
    public class PosPsact implements IPospsact {
)
```

*Generating Query*

```
FROM vw_f_t_bucket tbucke0_
         INNER JOIN snp_prd posprd1_
            ON tbucke0_.prod_cycle_key = posprd1_.cycle_key
               AND tbucke0_.prod_key = posprd1_.prod_key

        JOIN FETCH t1.psAct                 

         INNER JOIN vw_ps_act_firm pospsn2_
            ON tbucke0_.ps_act_key = pspsn2_.ps_act_key

CROSS JOIN snp_prd posprd3_
CROSS JOIN vw_ps_act_firm pospsn5_
where tbucke0_.prod_cycle_key=posprd3_.cycle_key and tbucke0_.prod_key=posprd3_.prod_key and tbucke0_.posn_acct_key=pospsn5_.posn_act_key
```

As you can see from above hibernate is generating cross joins at the end. Why is that? How can I stop hibernate from generating those cross joins?

If I just use the hql like

```
"FROM TBucket t1  ";
```

It is generating

```
from vw_f_t_bucket tbucke0_ 
cross join snp_prd psprd1_ cross join vw_psn_act_firm pspsn3_
```

How can I make it do a regular join instead of a cross join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've both specified eager fetching and also indicated a JOIN FETCH in your query.  The JOIN FETCH is unnecessary as the property is already annotated for eager fetch (hence the inner joins in the FROM.)

Comment: I removed the JOIN FETCH, the JOIN FETCH in the "Generating Query" is gone, but the cross joins remain. What can I do about it?

Comment: Is that the entirety of the entities?  perhaps there are other mappings to those tables on the entity?  I've honestly never seen hibernate write a full cross join before.

Comment: the problem 
instead of using 
from TBucket t1 join t1.prd p 
and in Criteria, I should be using p.excgId in (?,?)
I was using Criteria like t1.prd.excgId in (?,?). That is the reason why it was generating cross joins.
I should be using the alias to do filtering.
Thanks for help, though.